# build.gradle.kts all line highlighted in red

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

I am currently working in a multi module application.

I'm not sure why but my build.gradle.kts file is all red as well as my settings.gradle.kts

I have tried, clearing the cache, recloning the repo's but it is still highlighted in red.

I've even tried changing the version of my gradle jdk and still this does not change anything

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution for me was to upgrade my android studio version to the latest version of android studio. So update to android Studio flamingo.